# Vega-Altair: alt.condition() on color with mark_point() vs. mark_line()

Tags: altair

I don't understand why the color=alt.condition() works with mark_point() but not with mark_line() in the example below:

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x=np.arange(100)
source_1 =pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'f(x)':np.sin(x/5),})
source_2=pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'f(x)':np.cos(x/5),})

source_1['Valid']=source_1['x'].apply(lambda x: x<50)
source_1['Sample']=1

source_2['Valid']=source_2['x'].apply(lambda x: x<50)
source_2['Sample']=2

source=pd.concat([source_1,source_2])

curve_mp =alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
    x='x',
    y='f(x)',
    color=alt.condition(alt.expr.datum['Valid']==True,alt.Color('Sample:N'),alt.ColorValue('lightgrey')),
    detail='Sample'
    )

curve_ml =alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x='x',
    y='f(x)',
    color=alt.condition(alt.expr.datum['Valid']==True,alt.Color('Sample:N'),alt.ColorValue('lightgrey')),
    detail='Sample'
    )

curve_mp | curve_ml
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIZob.png)

The mark_point() chart behaves as I expect, but the mark_line() doesn't.

I have ended up in a layer of two charts using subdatasets :

`curves2=alt.Chart(source[source['Valid']==True]).mark_line().encode(x='x',y='f(x)',color=alt.Color('Sample:N'),detail='Sample')`

but I am wondering whether an alternative exists.

Many thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Vega bug. It also works without the condition (in that a line mark can have multiple colors). There is a way around it by adding another encoding for "Valid". You still have a gap between, which you could solve adding a duplicate data row.

Using `detail`, you get the following:

```
curve_ml =alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x='x',
    y='f(x)',
    color=alt.condition(alt.datum.Valid==True, alt.Color('Sample:N'), alt.ColorValue('lightgrey')),
    detail='Valid'
)
```

[image: detail]

If you want a legend entry, you can use `opacity` (or any other).

```
curve_ml =alt.Chart(source).mark_line().encode(
    x='x',
    y='f(x)',
    color=alt.condition(alt.datum.Valid==True, alt.Color('Sample:N'), alt.ColorValue('lightgrey')),
    opacity=alt.Opacity('Valid:N').scale(domain=[False], range=[1,1]),
)
```

[image: opacity]